# Get the executable path of running process

Tags: node.js, path, process, wmic, ps

I wish to get the executable path of running process. Say I have two nginx executables running.

```
C:/nginx/nginx.exe (or say usr/bin)
C:/second/nginx/nginx.exe (or say $home/local/nginx)
```

I wish to get the executable's path of the running nginx file whether it is the first or second. I am aware of this command `wmic process where "ExecutablePath like 'c:\\nginx\\nginx%'" get ProcessID` in windows.

Is there a way I can do it using node process for windows and linux both together? I am currently looking at this - `ps-node` https://github.com/neekey/ps/issues/83